# CSS not apply when move to other URL/route

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5.1

### 1- Step one correct work

1 index.blade.php page

```
<nav class="navigation">
              <ul class="sf-menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('about') }}">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;">Category</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('grid') }}">Buy and Sell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="agent-detail.html">Car and Vehicles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="my-properties.html">Real Estate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="submit.html">Pets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pricing.html">Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Community</a></li>
                    <li><a href="404.html">Resumes</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
```

2 Route code

```
Route::resource('/', 'BasicController');
Route::resource('about', 'BasicController@about');
Route::resource('contact', 'BasicController@contact');
Route::resource('grid', 'BasicController@grid');
```

3 BasicController code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BasicController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {  
        return view('index');
    }

    public function about()
    {   
       return view('about');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
       return view('contact');
    }

     public function grid()
    { 
        return view('buy-and-sell/grid');
    }

    public function create()
    {
       //
    }
}
```

4 view image for help 
[image: for you help]
5 correct work

### 2- In this step css not work

please help in this step

1 index.blade.php page. grid/1 pass to url and equal to if or elseif statement

```
<nav class="navigation">
              <ul class="sf-menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('about') }}">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;">Category</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('grid/1') }}">Buy and Sell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="agent-detail.html">Car and Vehicles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="my-properties.html">Real Estate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="submit.html">Pets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pricing.html">Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Community</a></li>
                    <li><a href="404.html">Resumes</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
```

2 Route code

```
Route::resource('/', 'BasicController');
Route::resource('about', 'BasicController@about');
Route::resource('contact', 'BasicController@contact');
Route::resource('grid', 'BasicController@grid');
```

3 BasicController code

```
class BasicController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {  
        return view('index');
    }

    public function about()
    {   
       return view('about');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
       return view('contact');
    }

    public function grid(Request $request, $id)
    {  

        if ($id == 1) {
           return view('buy-and-sell/grid');
        }
        elseif ($id == 2) {
            return view('car-and-vehicels/grid');
        }
        elseif ($id == 3) {
            return view('country/grid');
        }
        else{
             return view('other/grid');
        }

    }

    public function create()
    {
       //
    }
}
```

4 image for your help 
[image: image for you help]
css is not work

Comment: Can you share head part of your `index.blade.php` where you link your CSS?

Comment: I am not sure how is your app architecture, but it seems, in step 2, you didn't pass any variable through route `Route::resource('grid', 'BasicController@grid');` to catch the `$id` in your `grid()` function ?

Comment: index.blade.php header show

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Please upvote if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scrip src and link href as folloing

```
<link href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/plugins/prettyphoto/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/plugins/owl-carousel/css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/plugins/owl-carousel/css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!-- custom css apply -->
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/css/ie.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<!-- Color Style -->
<link href="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/colors/color1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- SCRIPTS
  ================================================== -->
<script src="{{ URL::to('/')}}/template/js/modernizr.js"></script><!-- Modernizr -->
```

When you move to another route, your href can't find the css files.

Also you need to **Update** your route from

```
Route::resource('grid', 'BasicController@grid');
```

to

```
Route::resource('grid/{$id}', 'BasicController@grid');
```

so that your `grid(Request $request, $id)` function can receive the `$id` from the url.

Answer (score 0):

### index.blade.php page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Real Spaces - @yield('title')</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
<link href="template/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="template/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="template/plugins/prettyphoto/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="template/plugins/owl-carousel/css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="template/plugins/owl-carousel/css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="template/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!-- custom css apply -->
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<!-- Color Style -->
<link href="template/colors/color1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- SCRIPTS
  ================================================== -->
<script src="template/js/modernizr.js"></script><!-- Modernizr -->
</head>
<html>
<head>
```

This is my Master header in laravel for all page

Comment: You need to put this in your question by updating the question as its part of your question.. not answer.